# Ubuntu 14.04 battery drainage when shut off

Tags: power-management, shutdown, battery

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed on a Lenovo Thinkpad T430s. The battery management worked fine until about 2-3 weeks ago. Now, however, my battery drains faster, even when the laptop is shut off. In fact, during one night, about 50 % of the battery is consumed. I have tested a second battery - but it's the same issue. I have not done any changes in BIOS - all the quick startup options are disabled.
Is it possible that the problem comes from a recent update? I am only an advanced user of Linux - but by no ways an expert.
Thank you very much for your help and your ideas. 
Regards, 
Robert

Comment: No, I don't just close the lid - I 'really' shut down the computer, using the power icon in the upper right corner.

Comment: thanks for your reply. No, I didn't close the lid when I observed this problem. I left the lid open.

Answer (score 0):

To confirm whether or not this is in fact Ubuntu and not simply the battery aging, try manually shutting down:

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

That will ensure it truly powering down. If the battery then still drains, you know it's not Ubuntu that is causing it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this tonight - and post the result tomorrow. However, I am using 2 batteries (regular battery and bay battery). Additionally, I bought a new battery - so in total I tested the problem with 3 batteries - always the same issue.

Comment: Hello, if I shut it down manually, the battery does not drain. Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on a Lenovo Thinkpad E560. I am facing nearly the same problem, losing battery power when power off or standby. This can't be a battery aging problem since i bought my laptop one month ago. I found this issue https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=180496 which helped me to solve the problem, just disable the Wake-On-Lan from the Bios.